# append data from form to column

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am working on a "issue tracker" access data base where the user enters there data through forms, create new form and edit form.

I have a comment section on my edit form which I have been requested to remained lock, for viewing purposes. So the user can only view the comments.
I have another box below that must "append" or add data to the comment section with a time and user stamp.

My approach is to create a vba code that will allow the user to enter data, and once entered will show in the locked comment section. As the user is working through a "editing" form.

I am fairly new to access and vba and unfortunately I cant find anything that I understand online.

Below is some code use and found searching online. I have but can figure out how to append ( or add ) it to the existing column. It is running fine but the data value I wish to add don't go anywhere?

```
Private Sub Add_Click()

Dim StrSQL As String
Dim addComments As String

' where addcomment.value is the value desire to append
addCommentStr = Me!addComment.Value

'where IssueTrack is Table, AdditionalComments is column
StrSQL = "INSERT INTO IssueTracker(AdditionalComments) VALUES ('" & 
addCommentStr & "' );"

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL StrSQL
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

MsgBox ("Comment Added")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't just keep on appending text to the same record. Where would you end?

So, skip all the code and create a form bound to the table.

Have one field for the date. Set its *DefaultValue* to: Now()

Set the form's property *AllowEdits* to: False